# `fatal: ambiguous argument` when run `git filter-branch`

Tags: git

I use `git 1.8.3.1` in centos 7.
I want to `rm -cached` `favicon.ico`,`favicon2.ico`,`sample.ico...` in my repo current status.
My script got error as below:

```
    [root@localhost www]# git filter-branch "git rm --cached '*.ico'" HEAD
    fatal: ambiguous argument 'git rm --cached '*.ico'': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
    Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
    'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

What's the problem?

Comment: That's not the right way to use `filter-branch`. Based on the `rm --cached` part, you probably wanted that string-literal as an argument to `--index-filter`. (But are you sure you want to use `filter-branch` at all? Remember, it's going to copy *many* commits, applying that command during each copy.)

Comment: @torek,is `git filter-branch --index-filte "git rm --cached '*.ico'"  HEAD` ok?do I nedd `HEAD` as I just want to remove files in current SHA1.

Comment: Globbing is not done by git. Maybe remove the single quotes around `*.ico`?

Comment: If you want to remove *.ico from all the commits of the current branch, try `git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -f *.ico" HEAD`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: actually, Git *does* do globbing. Anywhere a command takes a "pathspec" the default is to do glob-style expansion. @kittygirl, if you only want to displace the *current* commit with a new one, don't use `git filter-branch` at all, use `git commit --amend` instead.

Comment: @torek Ah. I had been misinformed. Now I know

Comment: @evolutionxbox yeah, the results can be ... surprising, on a Linux-ish system, when your shell passes `*` through when there's no match and Git (because it's using the index or a commit instead of the work-tree) finds a match. :-)

Comment: @ElpieKay,only want to delete from latest commit

Comment: @kittygirl then change `HEAD` to `HEAD^..`. But if it's the last commit, you could just use `git rm -f *.ico;git commit --amend`.